# need to show highest value by adding in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

```
   <td><input type="text" name="oweight[]" id="oweight[]"  class="form-control input-sm mb15 wweight" required  maxlength="5" onkeypress="javascript:return isNumber (event)" required></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="orweight[]" id="orweight[]" class="form-control input-sm mb15 rweight" onblur="wtotal()" maxlength="5" required onkeypress="javascript:return isNumber (event)" required></td>
   <div class="col-sm-12">
   <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Total Weight:</label>
   <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" style="text-align:left;" id="weight"></label> </div>
```

The largest value from the weight and realweight should be selected and display in totalweight.in case of more than one only highest value from weight and real weight should be added to each other.

[image]

```
function wtotal() {
    var wweight = document.getElementsByClassName("wweight");
    var rweight = document.getElementsByClassName("rweight");
    var total_wweight = 0;
    var total_rweight = 0;
    var total_tweight = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < wweight.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < rweight.length; j++) {


        if (parseInt(rweight[j].value) > parseInt(wweight[i].value)) {
            total_rweight=parseInt(rweight[j].value);
            total_tweight = total_tweight + total_rweight;
            console.log("total_rweight=="+total_rweight);

        } else {
            total_wweight= parseInt(wweight[i].value);
            total_tweight = total_tweight + total_wweight;
            //console.log("total_wweight=="+total_wweight);
        }
        //total_tweight =total_rweight + total_wweight;
        document.getElementById("weight").innerHTML =total_tweight;
        //console.log("total_tweight=="+total_tweight);
      }
    }
```

Comment: please see the image added

Comment: So what is your question? And what is the problem with your current code?

Comment: what is your question

Comment: _I can ignore this question for longer than you can wait for someone to do your coding for you._ Any chance of more specific details about your problem?

Comment: the highest value from weight and real weight should be selected

Comment: from each row and should be added and then display in total weight

Comment: So go ahead and do that then

Comment: done with this task by using only single for loop